# Google Analytics referral sources

Tags: google-analytics

We're using Google and Facebook SSO allowing our users to sign up and login with these services. However, if a user signs up or logins in with either service (rather than creating a standard email login), we lose the referral source in Google Analytics -- and, instead, sign up and upgrade sources are attributed to accounts.google.com or Facebook.com. Anyone have some thoughts on a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This requires some backend work. Whenever one of your users clicks on the login button with either services, you backend should 'remember' him using a cookie or any other parameter. In that way whenever he comes back from exactly the url of your Facebook SSO or accounts.google.com you should set the GA tracker referrer parameter to the one of your site's URL. You can do this in basic js code like this

```
ga('set', 'referrer', 'mydomain.com');
```

In this way you won't see these invalid referrals anymore.